# How to get only the specific value from series or list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, series

I have a data of over 600 employees' attendance over a period of month.

[Table Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9ncx.png)

I have to get the count of absents of each employee and write it to another excel sheet.

So I initiated a for loop as shown below:

[Code Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWmJI.png)

Im storing the value counts in a list and that includes the count of all variables in the row named status in picture 1.

How do I store only the count value of A(absent) in a list so I could use it accordingly.

Note: I know that status.loc['A'] gives the count of absent but when I try to use it in the loop it says key error.

[Status.loc['A']](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNsrh.png)

If I can't get the value of A from status.loc , is there a way to extract it from the list i stored it in named absent?

Please help me out!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please post your full code(not as image) and the expected output

Comment: It seems that your error occurred because on some of the rows you do not have 'A' at all, and therefore the loc[] cannot find it

Comment: Yes! that seems to be the case. Is there a way to put a default value 0 if key is not found??

Comment: NVM! I figured out that i can use x.get() instead of x[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just do error handeling:

```
try:
    absent.append(status.loc['A'])
except:
    <rest of code here>
```